# What are some of the best ways to get your Android application noticed after it leaves the 'Just In' section?

Tags: android, google-play

So I've recently released an application on to the Android Market. Whilst it was in the "Just In" section I was seeing decent download numbers, but since then interest seems to have dropped off significantly. I think now people can only find my app through a specific keyword search, which doesn't make me particularly confident about it ever becoming popular.

What can you do when your app has passed the 'Just In' stage but has not reached the 'Featured' stage? The majority of applications seem to be in this middle stage so I think other people must have a similar problem. It seems like the 'Featured' section just makes the [popular apps more popular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_rich_get_richer_and_the_poor_get_poorer), and makes it really difficult for newer apps to ever catch up with them. Does anyone know if the situation with the Apple App Store is any different?

It seems to be possible to refresh your app and make it appear in the 'Just In' section again if you update it sometime after, but I can't find any real guidelines on this. Is anyone familiar with the specific rules for this, and is repeatedly riding the 'Just In' buzz the only viable strategy for a new app?

Comment: [This](http://replicaisland.blogspot.com/2010/04/replica-island-one-month-on.html) is a good read. The Replica Island dev keeps LOTS of metrics.

Comment: I think this should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading that updating the app will bring it back to the top of that list... I googled it a bit and found this [blogger](http://blog.pseudoblue.com/2010/08/24/android-app-updates-get-to-the-top-of-the-just-in-list/) that recommends spacing out your updates to make it to the "just in" list. The writer points to another blogger that had a similar experience. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer a "Just In" section so this answer is out-of-date.

There is now no way to get noticed if you don't do advertising. Your app will remain at the bottom of the list with zero downloads and no ratings forever unless you do marketing, get reviews, etc.

Even having a demo won't help because no-one will ever see it since it will be 50-60 pages ahead.